# Installing jetty on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: configuration, jetty, ubuntu-11.10

I have installed Jetty on Ubuntu server 11.10.  When I start Jetty I get no errors and everything starts fine.  The console output is:

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/jetty restart
 * Stopping Jetty servlet engine (was reachable on http://jetway:8080/). jetty
 * Jetty servlet engine stopped. jetty
   ...done.
 * Starting Jetty servlet engine. jetty
 * Jetty servlet engine started, reachable on http://jetway:8080/. jetty
   ...done.
```

Here is a truncated version of /etc/init.d/jetty

```
NO_START=0
VERBOSE=yes
JETTY_USER=jetty
JETTY_HOST=0.0.0.0
JETTY_PORT=8080
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle"
```

When I try to access the default jetty index.html my browser times out.  My error file does not contain any errors.  I also downloaded the war for jamwiki and dropped it into the /webapps folder.  The log file states that it initializes, but I cannot see it either.  I am not even seeing an error page, it is just the timed out page from Safari.  I assume I am missing some config or something is setup wrong, but I dont know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

have a fw going or anything like that?

try using wget from localhost on that machine to see if that responds

make sure that it is not something like the JETTY_HOST not getting the update from that configuration, if that is the case edit the jetty.xml file and change the host on the connector in question

Comment: It downloaded an index file from an app that is running on my Apache2 instance.  Wierd....

Comment: so it is accessible via localhost, i suspect the JETTY_HOST configuration isn't going through, edit the jetty.xml file and change the value to 0.0.0.0

Comment: I changed that comment above.

Comment: o.O what url are you trying to access? you are adding the port I hope, that your getting apache indicates your talking to server other then jetty

Comment: if apache is responding then you have apache on that port, not jetty, best sort that out first...try switching your JETTY_PORT to 9090 and connect to that

Comment: I changed the config file to 9090 and get the same error.  I tried to wget and this time the connection timed out.  I also ran a netstat and I see 9090 LISTENING.

Comment: I made a mistake, when jetty is running on port 8080, wget does not download anything.  I did not add the port number, so that is why it accessed the apache index file.  I get a connection timed out no matter what port I am running on.

Comment: if it works on localhost:9090 but not IP:9090 then edit the jetty.xml as mentioned above, otherwise something else is going on

Comment: It isnt working at all.  It times out no matter what port i am using.